# How to use text file as input to feed in the interactive input of smalltalk and redirect output to a file

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I am struggling to find out is there a way to feed input
to the interactive command of `gst a.st b.st ... -`
and redirect the output. Normally, the interactive buffer will
have `st> ...` and when you type a command it will output something by calling
the default/override `displayString` method to the interactive output. How to get the input
and feed the output using linux command or maybe a tiny smalltalk test script to do that.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify a little more how exactly you want it to work? Do you want to get input from a file instead of entered live from the user? Do you want all the output going to a file? If the prompted input is one line at a time, e.g., using the Stream>>nextLine selector, you can synchronize line inputs from a file with the prompts and not have to get fancy and write a script that matches up prompts with inputs. I recommend `printNl` instead of `displayString` for output to `stdout`.

Comment: For the second and third questions, the answer is yes and it is one line at a time. If you could provide a detailed answer on how to use `Stream` with `printNl` as an answer below, it would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a contrived demonstration program. It reads in strings from standard input until EOF, sorts them, then prints them out:

```
input := stdin nextLine.
c := OrderedCollection new.

[ input ~= nil ] whileTrue: [
    c add: input.
    input := stdin nextLine.
].

c sort do: [ :each | each printNl ]
```

You can run it interactively (pressed Ctrl-D after entering `hhh`):

```
$ gst sortprog.st
tttt
aaa
vvvv
hhh
'aaa'
'hhh'
'tttt'
'vvvv'
```

Or I can create a text file `test.in` with the following contents:

```
tttt
aaa
vvvv
hhh
```

Then run:

```
$ gst sortprog.st < test.in > test.out
```

And then check the contents of the output file:

```
$ cat test.out
'aaa'
'hhh'
'tttt'
'vvvv'
```

If your program has prompts, they will appear in the output file, of course. Anything going to `stdout` will go to that file.